# How to do a foreach loop with multiple lists

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to do a `foreach` loop that runs through 3 lists. Here is what I have currently:

```
foreach (Button btn in appList && sequenceLsit && FunctionList)
{
    if (btn.FillColor != Color.White) 
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

I tried using tuples, but as I understand, they use a separate variable for each list. I need a single variable (btn) for all 3 lists.

Comment: I know that you were probably just throwing stuff at the wall but think about what the `&&` operator does. It takes two `bool` inputs and returns a `bool` output that is `true` if both inputs are `true` and `false` otherwise. How could it possibly be applicable in this case?

Comment: For the record, I just searched the web for "c# join multiple lists" and the very first result was information about the `Concat` method. A critical part of being a developer is being able to find existing information.

Comment: Are all the lists of Type `List<Button>`? What is `FillColor`? Do you mean `ForeColor`? -- Are you trying to change the `ForeColor` (or whatever) of all Buttons? In that case, you can bind that Property (or any other bindable Property) to the Project's Settings and just change the Setting's value to change the associated Property of all Buttons (or any other Control, for that matter) in one strike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `foreach` loop enumerates one list. If you have three separate lists then you need to create one list from them first, which can then be enumerated. The simplest way to do that is the `Enumerable.Concat` extension method:

```cs
foreach (Button btn in appList.Concat(sequenceLsit).Concat(FunctionList))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to solve this.
You can:

1. Iterate through each list one at a time (foreach inside foreach inside foreach) as mentioned by John
2. Union your lists together if they share the same type (how are your lists declared?) and then iterate through them once with a single foreach loop

Also, you can use LINQ to remove the need for the IF statement, like this:
foreach (var btn in appList.Where(x => x.FillColor != Color.White)) {...}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumerable.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-6.0) method

```
foreach (Button btn in appList.Concat(sequenceLsit).Concat(FunctionList))
{
    if (btn.FillColor != Color.White) 
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@John provided you with `.Concat`, but you may be able to solve your problem with a different approach:

1. Create method that works on a button

   ```
   var CheckButtons(IEnumerable<Button> buttons) 
   {
     foreach (Button btn in buttons)
     {
        if (btn.FillColor != Color.White) 
        {
           // Do stuff
        }
     }
   }
   ...
   ```
2. Call it on your lists:

   ```
   CheckButtons(appList);
   CheckButtons(sequenceLsit);
   CheckButtons(FunctionList);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72681396/9412456), if you're going with LINQ, why not go all the way?

```csharp
foreach (var btn in appList.Concat(sequenceList).Concat(FunctionList)
                           .Where(b => b.FillColor != Color.White))
{
  // do stuff with btn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to install the [System.Interactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/) package (owned by the [dotnetfoundation](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/dotnetfoundation)), and use the `EnumerableEx.Concat` method. It has this signature:

```
// Concatenates the input sequences.
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(
    params IEnumerable<TSource>[] sources);
```

Usage example:

```
foreach (Button btn in EnumerableEx.Concat(appList, sequenceList, functionList))
{
    //...
```

You can find the source code of this method [here](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/85f1eb7c53e27cccdbeee3e0b044916168843fcc/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/System/Linq/Operators/Concat.cs#L39-L48). It's pretty trivial.